# How to select an item from a table using jQuery, when a button is pressed in that row.

Tags: jquery

I'm going to explain this the best I can...

So I have a table that is dynamically generated and populated using jQuery. In each row of the table there is a button, when a button is pressed I need to select the text that is in the first column of that row.

For example:

If you imagine in the button column below there are actually buttons there. If for example I click the button2, then I need to select name2. How might I do this. 
[image: table]

I've got the handler for the button, and when I click the buttons the alert "clicked" appears.

```
            $("#mTable").on("click", ".buttons",
            function () {
                alert("clicked");
            })
```

Any ideas on how I can change the function so the corresponding name is selected when the button in the same row is pressed.

Comment: Please include a "*[mcve]*" snippet of your code in order that we can reproduce your problem/situation without having to first create what we think it is, or might be. This helps us to answer the question more precisely and helps you to get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` should hold the element being interacted with. 
Since you want to get elements on the same row, you could use `closest` to get the row itself, and find the appropriate child inside.

Something like this should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mTable").on("click", ".buttons", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
      $el = $tr.find('.name-span'), // or whatever your selector is
      name = $el.text();
    
    // (you can also shorten this up):
    // var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.name-span').text();

    alert(name + " clicked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name-span">Name 1</span></td>
    <td><span class="address-span">Address 1</span></td>
    <td><button class="buttons">Button 1</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name-span">Name 2</span></td>
    <td><span class="address-span">Address 2</span></td>
    <td><button class="buttons">Button 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name-span">Name 3</span></td>
    <td><span class="address-span">Address 3</span></td>
    <td><button class="buttons">Button 3</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You may also replace `.text()` with whatever you want to get from the element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over the HTML that is output?  If so, you can give each table cell in the name column a class.  If you do that, you can use jQuery to find table row `tr` that contains the button that was clicked, from there you can look inside for a cell with the class `.name` (just as an example) and return the value.

### HTML

```
<table id="mTable">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name">Name 1</span></td>
    <td><span class="address">Address 1</span></td>
    <td><button class="buttons">Button 1</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name">Name 2</span></td>
    <td><span class="address">Address 2</span></td>
    <td><button class="buttons">Button 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="name">Name 3</span></td>
    <td><span class="address">Address 3</span></td>
    <td><button class="buttons">Button 3</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### JS

```
$("#mTable").on("click", ".buttons", function () {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.name').text());
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoReBP